# Fill array with months using loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

```
function dateColumn() {
    var startDate = new Date($("#anStartDate").val()); //the start date
    var pmtPeriods = $("#anPaymentPeriods").val(); //number of months in this case
    var dateData = new Array(pmtPeriods);
    var i = 0;
    while (i < pmtPeriods) {
        startDate = startDate.add(i).month();
        dateData[i] = startDate;
        i++
    }
    alert(dateData);
}
```

Let's say my start date is `2014-01-01` and I put 2 months as `pmtPeriods`. That fills my array with `[2014-02-01, 2014-02-01]`. If I take `pmtPeriods` as 3 with same start date result is `[2014-03-01, 2014-03-01, 2014-03-01]`. This is wrong.

With pmtPeriods 2 I would like result:

```
[2014-02-01, 2014-03-01]
```

instead of

```
[2014-02-01, 2014-02-01]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: "With pmtPeriods 2 i would like result: [2014-02-01, 2014-03-01]" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding startDate to the dateData array 3 times. That's just adding a reference to the startDate value which is getting updated in your loop. Change:

```
dateData[i] = startDate;
```

to

```
dateData[i] = new Date(startDate);
```

Comment: Oh...sometimes you feel you are so close but can't solve it. This solved my problem (blaming working all day ;-)). Thank you!